# Rails production server config.cache_classes = true does not reload custom service classes correctly for active job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I'm using Active Job with sidekiq adapter in Rails 6.1.3.2

Strangely, custom service singleton methods are lost when they're called in Active Job.

**notify_message_event_job.rb**

```rb
module Chats
  class NotifyMessageEventJob < ApplicationJob
    queue_as: default

    def perform(message:, event:)
      Rails.logger.info(PushNotification::Service.name)
      Rails.logger.info(PushNotification::Service.singleton_methods.inspect)
      PushNotification::Service.create(
        user: message.user,
        notification: message.content
      )
    end
  end
end
```

**lib/push_notification/service.rb**

```rb
module PushNotification
  class Service
    class << self
      def create(user:, notification:)
        // 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The following line:

```rb
NotifyMessageEventJob.perform_now(message: message, event: event)
```

produces the following error:

> [ActiveJob] [Chats::NotifyMessageEventJob] [b1d934c8-afe0-44a0-bc22-44d40eea7d3d] Performing Chats::NotifyMessageEventJob (Job ID: b1d934c8-afe0-44a0-bc22-44d40eea7d3d) from Sidekiq(default) enqueued at  with arguments: {:message=>#<GlobalID:0x00007fe5bc4f6b00 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://interview-server/ChatMessage/156>>, :event=>"NEW_MESSAGE"}
>
> [ActiveJob] [Chats::NotifyMessageEventJob] [b1d934c8-afe0-44a0-bc22-44d40eea7d3d] PushNotification::Service
>
> [ActiveJob] [Chats::NotifyMessageEventJob] [b1d934c8-afe0-44a0-bc22-44d40eea7d3d] [:yaml_tag]
>
> [ActiveJob] [Chats::NotifyMessageEventJob] [b1d934c8-afe0-44a0-bc22-44d40eea7d3d] Error performing Chats::NotifyMessageEventJob (Job ID: b1d934c8-afe0-44a0-bc22-44d40eea7d3d) from Sidekiq(default) in 40.9ms: NoMethodError (undefined method `create' for PushNotification::Service:Class):

As you can see in the log, class `PushNotification::Service` is correctly loaded, but there is only `yaml_tag` method.

When I run the following method in rails console:

```
2.7.3 :001 > PushNotification::Service.singleton_methods
```

I get:

> => [:create, :ios_app_name, :config, :create_apnsp8_app, :create_apns2_app, :create_android_app, :create_ios_apps, :flush, :notification_enabled?, :create_gcm_notification, :create_apn_notification, :android_app_name, :yaml_tag]

RSpec tests are also passed. I get this error in production server. What's the reason? I'm pulling out of my hair.

**UPDATE**

I found out that if I set `config.cache_classes = false`, the code will proceed without any problem.

However, as soon as I reset `config.cache_classes = true`, the same error will happen again. Of course, I restart production rails server every time I change my code.

I deleted the entire source code, rebooted the server. Pull the code again and restarted rails, but the problem does not disappear.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you use for deployment? Does it run in a container or do you use passenger or some other solution?

Comment: @DennyMueller I just use puma + nginx

Comment: How do you restart the puma?

Comment: @DennyMueller I just restart using `sudo systemctl restart app`. app.service starts rails server with `rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -e production`

Comment: Mhm maybe there is your issue somewhere hidden. When the app runs check what services are running with `htop/top/ps aux`. There should be rails and puma running.
Although I though that puma only will be used if the rails server gets started with the `puma` command. Try to kill all processes before starting your app again. I had the issue in the past that puma spawned multiple processes which were used but not restarted or killed properly. Since the old processes still have the old code and will be reused you got your "caching" issue
Additionally: https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1253

Comment: No worries. At least you were able to circumvent it and make it a technical debt :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seemed like it was an issue with [zeitwerk autoloading mode](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) which was introduced as default in Rails 6

I temporarily opted out in config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.load_defaults 6.1
config.autoloader = :classic
```